# problem in extend string limit in generate excel file

Tags: php, excel, pear, export-to-excel

I am using phpxls library for generating excel file.
but it has a string limit of 255 characters in each cell and my string is greater then 255.

How can i extend this string limit?

I have tried to change in library for change the variable value. but when excel file will generate then it is giving me alert "data may have been lost."

What to do? please help me.

Answer (score 1):

i believe it's a limitation of .xls (2000 - 2003) format, maximum 255 characters / cell

http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=264626